# Installing python 3.9 on Cloudera CDSW without sudo

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloudera, cdsw

I am trying to install Python 3.9 on Linux 4.4 in Cloudera Data Science Workbench (cdsw).. I do not have sudo rights and I wont be able to connect to any websites.
The current version of python is 3.6
Following the procedure [as mentioned here.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

However, on step "sudo make altinstall" I get the error "permission denied" on /usr/local/bin

Is there any workaround to make this step work?
This is the last step of the whole procedure.

Comment: Why are you installing from source (2) and not from apt (1)? With deadsnakes ppa added, it's all a breeze and you'll be able to install newer (or older) versions without any additional steps, just using apt. Source is useful only if you want to customise your build (even linuxize says so)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method on top and install using apt... It's the best way to do it,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Followed by adding the repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Accept the changes, then

```
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Now, whenever you want to use python3.9 you have to invoke python3.9 instead of python3.

If you are using cloudera, cdsw, you cannot get sudo rights, you need to follow this guide to install packages,

https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/1-8-x/topics/cdsw_extensible_engines.html

Follow the guide above, then change the docker file like this

```
# Dockerfile

FROM docker.repository.cloudera.com/cdsw/engine:8
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3.9 python3-pip \
   && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
RUN pip install pandas numpy
```

Then follow the rest of the guide for steps 2-4, you should be able to get your desired outcome.

Comment: I am working on cdsw..I do not have sudo rights and I wont be able to connect to any websites...any other workaround?

Comment: you should have said earlier, i updated my answer, from what i know you cant get sudo access you need to do the settings in the settings before you create the instance

Comment: @AmyJack I have updated my answer on how you can create a cdsw instance with the desired settings, please let me know if it works

Comment: Don't you still need sudo access to do docker things?

Comment: From the cdsw documentation it doesn’t look like you do

Comment: @AmyJack did my answer work?